# using python and urllib2 how to authenticate to a webpage before reading the source code

Tags: python, authentication

ok, so I have a code that is designed to read from a webpage and parse the source to find the amount of money in my google adsense accout. the read from part goes something like this:

```
import urllib2
import re
s = urllib2.urlopenopen('https://www.google.com/adsense/report/overview?timePeriod=alltime').read()
results = re.findall('[$][1-9][1-9][1-9][.][1-9][1-9]',s)
print results
```

so the code is working fine, except for the fact that to access my account i have to login(duh) but my issue is that i have no idea how to use python to authenticate at the login page and then move on to the account page. all i need to know is how to authenticate and then move onto the page that displays my account info, and by the way im using python 2.7, thanks very much!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/), a third-party package that acts like a browser.

The idea would be to get mechanize to fill the authentication forms you would normally fill manually while at your browser.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid, you are going to have much luck trying to get easy solution for what you are trying to do.

First of all, there is no `open` method with urllib2. What you might be trying is `urllib2.urlopen`

You might first want to know more about Authentication using urllib2. [This link](http://personalpages.tds.net/~kent37/kk/00010.html) provides some information.

In your specific case of Authenticating against google adsense, you will have to find out which urls and cookie is Google Adsense expecting for authentication before you launch upon a digest based authentication method. There is [poster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164680/how-to-login-to-new-google-adsense-from-code-c-or-java-or-python) who tried to do the same, but without much luck.

The best way to get data programmatically from Google is using their APIS, and in this case [Google Adsense API](http://code.google.com/apis/adsense/developer/index.html), there are [reporting API](http://code.google.com/apis/adsense/developer/ReportService.html)s listed, and you may want to use [SOAPpy](http://diveintopython.net/soap_web_services/introspection.html) to introspect and get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Web page authentication is up to the website, and can be done in numerous ways, you typically need to add headers or cookies to the request. How these headers should look depends on the webapplication again, and if you use http or https, and the cookies are typically something you get back when you go to a log-in page, which means you need to then make a request to the login page and keep track of those cookies.

So, before we can tell you how to do it in Python, you should figure out how to do it. How does the google adsense authentication work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm betting there is a python library out there for logging in to google services. Maybe you can hijack that for your uses?